# How do I create multiple time zones by using the NOW formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-timestamp, google-sheets-dates, time-zone

I'm trying to create 5 cells with different time zones: 
CDT MDT MST PDT EDT

I am in MST, so I obviously get my current time by doing

`NOW()`

How do I add hours to that? I tried

`NOW()+(2,0,0)`

But all I got was an error. I also got errors when I tried

`A1 + (2,0,0)` and `A1 *(2,0,0)`

Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- to add +1 hour: **`=NOW()+(1/24)`**

[image: 0]

- to add -2 hours:

[image: 0]

- more examples:

[image: 0]

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you! How do I make it so that I just see the hour and not the date? Also is there a way that I can do 12hr time instead of military time?

Comment: @TylerGarver answer updated

Comment: `=TEXT(NOW()+(1/24), "h:mm:ss am/pm")`

Comment: PSA to other readers with similar questions: Sheets does not actually handle time zones natively—the above naturally depends utterly on your math. Second, if these TZ conversions are mission-critical, note that for the few hours twice a year in which Daylight- and Standard- changes sweep across the zones, they stop having those static offsets. Or your situation may differ further—some zones don't change, some have odd changes, your worldwide offsets could even be wrong half the year. Anything tricky? Use Apps Script! [Fun video on problems](https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY).

Answer (score -2):

I found a simple answer, just do the =now()function and then format the cell lol, it worked for me :) https://www.excelhow.net/how-to-convert-time-format-from-12-hour-clock-to-24-or-24-to-12-hour-clock-in-excel.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).